# When used with uwsgi, redis APPENDs value instead of SETing it

Tags: python, nginx, redis, flask, uwsgi

I am using the following stack:

- nginx
- uwsgi
- Python (Flask)

I've set up a little app that utilizes redis as its main database. I only use GET, SET, EXISTS and EXPIRE in my code.

When trying the app in the terminal everything works fine. On every request it checks if the content is available (EXISTS). If it's not the content gets loaded and saved for a while (SET, EXPIRE). After that, the content gets presented to the user (GET).

The problem is that as soon as I run the app via nginx/uwsgi, after some time the EXPIRE seems to be ignored. Instead of deleting the value and loading it fresh, the new content gets appended to the old one - as it seems not only one time, but like dozens of times, resulting in extremely large values and sometimes timeouts.

Strangest thing for me: The whole issue disappears as soon as I restart uwsgi.
Any Idea?

Comment: Perhaps you're experiencing some kind of race condition? Try using `SETEX` instead of `SET` and `EXPIRE`, also enclose `EXISTS` and `SETEX` with `MULTI` and `EXEC`, so they'll be in the same transaction.

Comment: How about some code demonstrating the problem?

Comment: @Marcin: Sorry, forgot to add a link to the repo: https://github.com/saibotd/hackerhub/blob/master/app.py

Comment: @AudriusKažukauskas, I've made the suggested changes (which make a lot of sense, thanks!). so far, everything runs smoothly. I'd like to wait two more days, before I'd say it's fixed.

Comment: As a matter of courtesy, it would be good if you excerpted the most relevant portions in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out! The problem was that I "recycled" these two instances:

```
md = markdown.Markdown(safe_mode="escape", output_format='html4')
h2t = html2text.HTML2Text()
```

http://github.com/saibotd/hackerhub/blob/master/app.py -> lines 22, 23

I need to re-create these objects every request and it works as expected.